# Organization details missing from membership online receipts for on behalf of function

Tags: civimember, receipts

Civi 4.7.26 and Civi 4.7.27, Drupal 7.56

We've run into an issue where the information from the on behalf of profile for organizations is not appearing in the online membership receipt sent to the constituent.  We've tested this both with a more complex profile (with some custom fields included) and with the basic on behalf of profile - same result for both.  There are no contact subtypes involved (there is a JIRA issue related to the on behalf of profile and fields for specific contact subtypes).  Has anyone else run across this issue?

Thanks in advance.